# will google search ranking pick up on facebook posts?

Tags: facebook

Will google search rankings pick up on links posted by someone as a status increasing the rank of the add(link building)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
I tried to get all indexed webpage of FB. I don't see any specific posts in the list. Other places where you see posts (ex. your profile) is asynchronously loaded, so no crawling there.
[https://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Afacebook.com&oq=site%3Afacebook.com&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i58.3257j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=site:facebook.com&start=290](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Afacebook.com&oq=site%3Afacebook.com&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i58.3257j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3afacebook.com&start=290)